# Show ComboBox List on KeyPress at text location using ICSharpCode.TextEditor

Tags: c#

I'm using C# for starters. Now, I need some help showing the ComboBox List on KeyPress. I have it NOW to show the ComboBox at the Cursor Position, but it doesn't work properly. I would like to get it at a specific character position. For example:

```
this.   -- This will show the ComboBox list.
```

Here is my current code:

```
    private void m_editor_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        int x, y;
        x = Cursor.Position.X;
        y = Cursor.Position.Y;
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)58)
        {
            _methodBox.Show();
            _methodBox.Location = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
```

If TextEditorControl had

```
GetPositionFromCharIndex
```

It would make everything easier.

Anyway, Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show..? doesn't make sense..

Comment: How can it "NOT" make sense? It is specifically right in front of you. I want to show a "ComboBox".

Comment: You want to show a combox in the x y coordinates...? if so then where are you creating the new ComboBox that's what I am saying..

Comment: Well, that is just what I have so far. I want to show the ComboBox where the KeyPressed activated it. Like, when you're coding in C#, or C++, you use "." for C# to show the methods and "->" for C++ to show the methods. Without the quotations of course. :P

Answer (score 0):

if this shows anything at all then you need to switch the code around from

```
    _methodBox.Show();
   _methodBox.Location = new Point(x, y); 

   to
   _methodBox.Location = new Point(x, y); 
   _methodBox.Show();
```

also the key you are checking is ":" are you aware of that

Comment: Yes, I am aware char 58 is a Colon & Semicolon. What I want is to show the ComboBox once you have pressed the : key at the correct location. I don't want to use the cursor position.